# jQuery circular carousel

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm just wondering if anyone can point me at a jQuery carousel, like the one on Land of Coder (http://www.landofcoder.com/our-porfolios/jquery-plugins.html) which loops continuously. we used the Land of Coder one, and of course the client wants when it gets to the last element, the system repeats at the first item, not rewind all the way to the start. I've had a look at the code, but I can't modify it to provide this functionality.

I've also tried writing one myself with arrays, but this hasn't proven successful (I don't have hover pausing or play/pause controls). Thanks to Martin Jepersen and Felix Kling for their help on this effort.

Any help would be much appreciated.

T

Comment: The 'landofcoder.com' link 404s, you might want to double-check the link.

Comment: Fixed; they misspelt 'portfolios' on their site.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Not my fault if I can spell and they can't!!! Thanks guys.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for that. And tsk @landofcoders, I expect better from the web... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) can do this. Use the `circular` option.

Comment: I can't add a custom navigation to jCarousel lite though, nor can I add play/pause buttons (I need all this for accessibility). Or can I, maybe I'm just missing something in the docs?

Comment: jCarousel Lite is the lite version of the jCarousel. I don't think you can pause using jCarousel, I overlooked that, sorry. However you can use next / prev controls using `btnPrev` and `btnNext`

Comment: Ok thanks Rich. I think it's as close as I'm going to get. I'll give it a go. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) is the best so far and has both [`autoscrolling`](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html) and [`circular`](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html) properties

Answer (score 0):

I really like caroufredsel.frebsite.nl
It'll do about anything you want it to do.